# upload file in chunks using restsharp to enable progress

Tags: restsharp

I am using Restsharp to upload files. I need to show progress bar, but got to know that they don't support uploading in chunks. Below is the portion of code which uploads, how to modify it to enable uploading in chunks? Its in file Http.Synch.cs

```
 private static HttpWebResponse GetRawResponse(HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            return (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Response is HttpWebResponse)
            {
                return ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Sujit

Comment: Maybe this helps you; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45665682/how-to-upload-multiple-files-with-restsharp