# How to upload multiple files with restsharp?

Tags: c#, http, file-upload, restsharp

I want to upload files to this api https://support.crowdin.com/api/add-file/

How can I create a parameter named `files` and add multiple files to it using RestSharp?

I wrote this code so far but it doesn't work, RestSharp does not seem to upload the file as intended.

```
        var addUrl = new Uri($"https://api.crowdin.com/api/project/{projectIdentifier}/add-file?key={projectKey}&json=");


        var restClient = new RestSharp.RestClient("https://api.crowdin.com");
        var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest($"api/project/{projectIdentifier}/add-file", RestSharp.Method.POST);
        request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;

        request.AddQueryParameter("key", projectKey);
        request.AddQueryParameter("json", "");

        var files = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>
        {
            { "testfile", File.ReadAllBytes(fileName) }
        };
        request.AddParameter("files", files, RestSharp.ParameterType.RequestBody);

        var restResponse = restClient.Execute(request);
```

This gives me

```
{
  "success":false,
  "error":{
    "code":4,
    "message":"No files specified in request"
  }
}
```

Comment: @SirRufo The question you linked is about adding a single file. This question is about adding an array of files, which is not straightforward.

Comment: There is an answer (6 upvotes) with a sample for adding two files.

Comment: The answer is adding two files directly to the request whereas my case is more complicated. I have to add multiple files into an "array" named "files". (So I need to have control over the array name).

Comment: You have to post a Multipart/form request to the API. Each field needs a unique name. The field name may contain square brackets. The receiver may interpret the fields with square brackets as an array. Did you get the point?

Comment: @SirRufo That was literally the only thing I was missing. At least for me that was not obvious at all. Thank you very much! I'll edit my post to give a more detailed explanation of what went wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

@SirRufo mentioned the solution in the comments but didn't post it as a soltion, so I'll explain it here.

The http POST method actually has no concept of arrays.
Instead having square brackets in the field names is just a convention.

This example code works:

```
        var restClient = new RestSharp.RestClient("https://api.crowdin.com");
        var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest($"api/project/{projectIdentifier}/add-file", RestSharp.Method.POST);
        request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

        request.AddQueryParameter("key", projectKey);
        request.AddQueryParameter("json", "");

        request.AddFile("files[testfile1.pot]", fileName);
        request.AddFile("files[testfile2.pot]", fileName);

        // Just Execute(...) is missing ...
```

No need to nest custom parameters or anything complicated like that.
Adding the files with this "special" name format is all it takes.

My mistake was thinking that the `files[filenamehere.txt]` part implied a more complex POST body than it really needed.